# Convergence in Hausdorff distance of intersection of closed linear subspaces with a given closed convex set

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, noncommutative-geometry, convex-analysis

I've run into the following problem when doing some work with non-commutative metric spaces, which seems like something people may have thought about before but I can't find anything on this problem in particular.

---

I have a Banach space $C$, and a $[0, \infty]$-valued lower semi-continuous seminorm $L$ on $C$, which is finite valued on a dense subset of $C$. Let $B$ be the subset of $C$ on which $L$ is at most $1$, which is closed, convex and balanced (but will typically have empty interior and be unbounded). Think of $L$ as like the Lipschitz seminorm on the Banach space of continuous functions on a compact metric space, equipped with the supremum norm.

Now suppose that $(J_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of closed linear subspaces of $C$, such that each $J_n$ is generated as a closed linear subspace by its intersection with $B$, and such that the sequence $J_n \cap B$ converges in the Hausdorff distance induced by the norm on $C$ to a closed set $A \subset B$, i.e. for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that any point of $J_n \cap B$ is within a distance $\epsilon$ of some point of $A$ and vice-versa.

Since each $J_n \cap B$ is closed, convex and balanced, it is pretty easy to show $A$ is also closed, convex and balanced. What I want to show is that $A$ is exactly the intersection of $B$ and the closed linear subspace $J$ generated by $A$, or come up with conditions on $L$ (equivalently $B$) that make this true.

---

Note that $J = \overline{\bigcup_{M>0}MA}$, since $A$ is balanced and convex (closure of the increasing union of dilations of $A$, no linear combinations necessary).

I know that $A$ is exactly the set of limits of convergent sequences $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset B$ with $b_n \in J_n \cap B$ for each $n$. So what I am asking boils down to being able to approximate any $b \in J$ with $L(b) \leq 1$ by such a sequence. The difficulty is then that $L$ is only lower-semicontinuous.

If it has any influence on the result, I am happy to assume that the image of $B$ in each quotient $C/J_n$ is compact. The particular setting I am interested in also takes $C$ to be a $C^*$-algebra and $(J_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to be a sequence of closed left ideals, but I feel like (hope) what I am asking for should only depend on the geometry of $B$.

I have found work of Gurarii (Openings and inclinations of subspaces of a Banach space, Teor. Funkts.
Funkts. Anal. Prilozh. 1 (1965) 194–204.) which considers the case when $L$ is just the norm on $C$, and similar ideas are considered and compared in work of Iusem and Seeger (Distances between Closed Convex Cones:
Old and New Results, Journal of Convex Analysis, 17 (2010) 1033-1055.), but these do not help in my particular situation.

Any insights people have or references that might be relevant would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Sean